# How do I find the properties of a resource with azure resource manager

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

How can I see the configuration of a resource in a resource group? I've provisioned a database through the portal and I'd like to see what that configuration is in the template language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Azure Resource Manager REST API to list the template deployments for your resource group. A reference to the API is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn848363.aspx).

Near the top of the response is a **templateLink** that you can follow to get the deployment template. For example, this is what I get back for one of my deployments where I used the *Web App + SQL Database* configuration from the Azure Portal to create a new web app.

[image]

Comment: just out of curiosity what tool is that?

Comment: It is called Postman.  A must-have IMO if you're doing any REST API development.  You can get it here: https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: You can also use the [ARMExplorer](https://resources.azure.com/) to explore the Azure Resource Manager API.

Comment: Awesome!  I completely forgot about the ARM Explorer.  Thanks Ben!