# How to save an existing Azure resource group into a Resource Manager template JSON file?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

During //build/ 2015, Mark Russinovich mentioned in passing that it is possible to take an existing Azure resource group and "suck out" its configuration into an ARM template. How does one go about doing that?

**Update**:

I know it is possible to use the [ARM REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790549.aspx) to get information on deployments that were created via a template in the first place and to use [ARM Explorer](https://resources.azure.com) to look at resource manager components, but is there a way to get a template definition for a resource group easily from scratch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the properties of a resource with azure resource manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971800/how-do-i-find-the-properties-of-a-resource-with-azure-resource-manager)

Comment: @RickRainey, I could be wrong (still digging) but it looks like the link you are referring to in that answer points to the template that was used to create the resource group in the first place. In my case, I created the resource group by hand, and would now like to turn it into a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [tweet](https://twitter.com/Michael_Jonsson/status/714908931009732614) it's possible now.

Go to `Resource group > Properties > Export template...`

Comment: Confirmed, it now works, sort of ("chokes" on classic resources). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it is not possible yet.

http://feedback.azure.com/forums/281804-azure-resource-manager/suggestions/7163577-ability-to-export-a-resource-group-as-a-template